# How to make a Deno script restart itself on crash?

Tags: exception, deno

The following code allows a Node script to restart itself on crash :

```js
import {
    spawn
} from 'node:child_process';
process.on(
    'uncaughtException',
    () => {
        process.once(
            'exit',
            () => spawn(
                process.argv.shift(),
                process.argv,
                {
                    cwd: process.cwd(),
                    detached: true,
                    stdio: 'inherit'
                }
            )
        );
        process.exit();
    }
);
```

What's its Deno equivalent ?

Some search results indicate that `unhandledRejection` is the Deno equivalent of `uncaughtException` but it does not turn out to be : the script kept crashing.

Comment: Did you use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent default handling?

Comment: If that doesn't work you might experiment with other lifecycle events: https://deno.com/manual@v1.28.0/runtime/program_lifecycle

Comment: I did. And yes I read that page already.

Answer (score 0):

There are other things that could cause a Deno process to crash beyond exceptions in V8 — those are just one class of termination cause in the runtime. (For example, the Deno CLI core is built with Rust, so a [panic](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+panic) could happen as well). Of course, this is true for all other runtimes — bugs and unhandled exception cases exist in all software.

Because the other types of errors can't be caught in your JS code, it's a better strategy to manage your processes externally, either using a dedicated process manager software, or at least some abstraction outside the process itself.

Deno currently has no built-in equivalent to the code you've shown, but you can create a process restarting abstraction without too much effort. Below I've included a simple, reproducible example that you can modify to suit your needs. It includes a state object for holding meta information that is used to inform decisions about whether or not to restart the child process after termination.

> Note, I've included several console statements for the purposes of demonstration output, but you might not want those in your actual version.

`./restart.ts`:

```ts
async function runScript(denoRunArgs: string[]): Promise<Deno.CommandStatus> {
  try {
    return await new Deno.Command("deno", {
      args: ["run", ...denoRunArgs],
      // stderr, stdin, and stdout are set to "inherit" by default for spawned
      // child processes, but you might want to be explicit to avoid breaking
      // changes (which have happened in the past):
      // Ref: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/17230
      stderr: "inherit",
      stdin: "inherit",
      stdout: "inherit",
    }).spawn().status;
  } catch (cause) {
    console.error(cause);
    return {
      code: 1,
      signal: null,
      success: false,
    };
  }
}

type ProcessState = {
  retryCount: number;
  status: Deno.CommandStatus;
};

// Determine your restart logic here:
function shouldRestart(state: ProcessState): boolean {
  return state.status.code !== 0 && state.retryCount > 0;
}

async function main() {
  const state: ProcessState = {
    retryCount: 2,
    status: {
      code: 1,
      signal: null,
      success: false,
    },
  };

  while (shouldRestart(state)) {
    console.error("Retry count:", state.retryCount);
    console.error("Starting script…");
    state.status = await runScript(Deno.args);
    console.error("Process terminated. Status:", state.status);
    state.retryCount -= 1;
  }

  if (state.status.code === 0) {
    console.error("Process completed successfully");
  } else {
    console.error("Process exceeded max retry count");
  }

  Deno.exit(state.status.code);
}

if (import.meta.main) await main();
```

`./example.ts`:

```ts
// After 1s delay:
setTimeout(() => {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    console.log("Success! Finishing.");
  } else {
    throw new Error("Failure! Crashing.");
  }
}, 1000);
```

You'll need to run the host process with `run` [permission](https://deno.com/manual@v1.33.1/basics/permissions) for `deno` itself (`--allow-run=deno`). After the path to the host script (`restart.ts`), include the other arguments that should be passed to the child `deno run` process — in this case, just the path to the child script:

```sh
deno run --allow-run=deno restart.ts example.ts
```

In the case that you need to provide permissions to the child script, etc. you could do it this way:

```sh
deno run --allow-run=deno restart.ts --allow-read example.ts child_arg_1 child_arg_2
```

---

Here are some outputs from running the non-deterministic example code above:

In the case that the child was successful on the first attempt:

```txt
% deno run --allow-run=deno restart.ts example.ts
Retry count: 2
Starting script…
Success! Finishing.
Process terminated. Status: { success: true, code: 0, signal: null }
Process completed successfully

% echo $?
0
```

In the case that the child failed on the first attempt, and succeeded on the second:

```txt
% deno run --allow-run=deno restart.ts example.ts
Retry count: 2
Starting script…
error: Uncaught Error: Failure! Crashing.
    throw new Error("Failure! Crashing.");
          ^
    at file:///Users/deno/so-76160618/example.ts:8:11
    at Object.action (ext:deno_web/02_timers.js:147:11)
    at handleTimerMacrotask (ext:deno_web/02_timers.js:64:10)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:172:21)
Process terminated. Status: { success: false, code: 1, signal: null }
Retry count: 1
Starting script…
Success! Finishing.
Process terminated. Status: { success: true, code: 0, signal: null }
Process completed successfully

% echo $?
0
```

In the case that the child failed on all attempts:

```txt
% deno run --allow-run=deno restart.ts example.ts
Retry count: 2
Starting script…
error: Uncaught Error: Failure! Crashing.
    throw new Error("Failure! Crashing.");
          ^
    at file:///Users/deno/so-76160618/example.ts:8:11
    at Object.action (ext:deno_web/02_timers.js:147:11)
    at handleTimerMacrotask (ext:deno_web/02_timers.js:64:10)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:172:21)
Process terminated. Status: { success: false, code: 1, signal: null }
Retry count: 1
Starting script…
error: Uncaught Error: Failure! Crashing.
    throw new Error("Failure! Crashing.");
          ^
    at file:///Users/deno/so-76160618/example.ts:8:11
    at Object.action (ext:deno_web/02_timers.js:147:11)
    at handleTimerMacrotask (ext:deno_web/02_timers.js:64:10)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:172:21)
Process terminated. Status: { success: false, code: 1, signal: null }
Process exceeded max retry count

% echo $?
1
```